# Error in creating store procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

I am getting error when I execute script mention below

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '$$

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `GetTopParentGivenDepth`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetTopParentGivenDepth`(GivenDepth INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE X,Y,x1,x2 INT;
    SET X = 0;
    SET Y = 1;
    SET @SQ = 'SELECT DISTINCT A0.id FROM categories A0';
    WHILE Y < GivenDepth DO
        SET @SQ = CONCAT(@SQ,' INNER JOIN categories A',Y,' ON A',X,'.id = A',Y,'.parent_id');
        SET X = Y;
        SET Y = X + 1;
    END WHILE;
    SET @SQ = CONCAT(@SQ,' WHERE A0.parent_id = 0');
    SELECT @SQ;
    PREPARE stmt FROM @SQ;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END$$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

missing DELIMITER before creating procedure

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `GetTopParentGivenDepth`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetTopParentGivenDepth`(GivenDepth INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE X,Y,x1,x2 INT;
    SET X = 0;
    SET Y = 1;
    SET @SQ = 'SELECT DISTINCT A0.id FROM categories A0';
    WHILE Y < GivenDepth DO
        SET @SQ = CONCAT(@SQ,' INNER JOIN categories A',Y,' ON A',X,'.id = A',Y,'.parent_id');
        SET X = Y;
        SET Y = X + 1;
    END WHILE;
    SET @SQ = CONCAT(@SQ,' WHERE A0.parent_id = 0');
    SELECT @SQ;
    PREPARE stmt FROM @SQ;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```